# How to load network image in Flame?

Tags: image, flutter, networking, game-engine, flame

In Flame documentation, Image class just load from asset folder.

```
bgSprite = Sprite('avatar/avatar-sample.png');
```

How can I load network images in Flame.

Comment: Post a piece of your code

Comment: Whats the purpose of accessing network image in flame?  Isn't it a game engine?

Comment: What if I want to show a user avatar as sprite?  Every sprite does not come from assets folder. At some point we need to get image from network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in versions after `1.0.0`:

```
import dart:ui; // This is the package you want the Image class from, there are several

Future<Image> getImage(String path) async {
  Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
  var img = new NetworkImage(path);
  img.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info,bool _){
    completer.complete(info);
  }));
  ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
  return imageInfo.image;
}
```

and then in your `onLoad` method, just initiate bgSprite:

```
@override
Future<void> onLoad() async {
  final image = await getImage("your-url.com/sample.png");
  bgSprite = Sprite(image);
}
```

In `0.28.0`, which it looks like you are running, you'll just replace the last line with (but I really recommend upgrading to a version after `1.0.0`):

```
bgSprite = Sprite.fromImage(image);
```